# jQuery counting spans in a div error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I'm not sure why but my code works fine in codepen but not on my actual site. On my site it logs 0 always.

```
var getSpans = [];

$('#hero span').parent()

.each(function(){
  getSpans.push({
    parent: this,
    spanCount: $(this).children('span').length
  });
});

console.log(getSpans.length);
```

Here's my codepen: http://codepen.io/Spiderian/pen/QwWweq

Comment: I think this is what you need: http://api.jquery.com/size/

Comment: var counter = $('#hero span').size(); console.log(counter);

Comment: @brandelizer - `The .size() method is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. Use the .length property instead.` ... `$('#hero span').length` return number of span inside `$('#hero')` or $('#hero > span') if you need to count direct Children of `#hero` element.

Comment: Youre right... var counter = $('#hero span').length; console.log(counter);

Comment: If your codepen is working then the code on your site is the issue not the .length property. No way to know without looking at your code but if it is returning 0 then you are likely targeting a parent element that has 0 span child elements. Double check element you're targeting.

Comment: maybe is useful to add a `console.log()` of `$('#hero span')` and `$('#hero span').parent()` to see if no element was matched.

Comment: var counter = $('#hero span').length; console.log(counter); Gives me the spans inside of spans as well so I can't use that one. The code above is THE only javascript I have running. The #hero is nested in 2 other divs and the body. Is that an issue?

Comment: and this: var counter = $('#hero>span').length; console.log(counter);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And this is why I hate Javascript. Wrapping it in a doc ready function fixed everything.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var getSpans = [];

$('#canvas #head #hero span').parent()

.each(function(){
  getSpans.push({
    parent: this,
    spanCount: $(this).children('span').length
  });
});

console.log(getSpans.length);
});
```